# How to add endpoints API jar to an android app?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jar, google-cloud-endpoints

I have build a Google App engine endpoints API and created its jar following the instructions as mentioned in the below link:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients

I have followed all the instructions and I have successfully created endpoints API jar. Now I want to use this jar to my android app.

In step # 5, this document says "Add the client library JAR to the Android app as described in [Using Endpoints in an Android Client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android)".

But nowhere in this document it is mentioned to how to integrate the jar that I have created.

Could anybody please help me out to **how to add google app engine endpoints JAR on an android app**?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using android studio or eclipse? Eclipse comes with a plugin that allows you to generate automatically and android studio makes it even easier to add so called "module"

Comment: Also once you add the jar you don't really integrate it, you just use it. Unless you are referring to adding it to the build path. To use the endpoint you can follow https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints

Comment: I am using android studio.

Comment: If you are using android studio, just follow the link I gave you. Does the link not work for you?

Comment: Thank you. I will check and let you know.